# Why would a .g.vb file for a WPF form not be generated in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a form in a WPF application that is generating an error message:

```
"BC30451: 'InitializeComponent()'is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level"
```

`InitializeComponent()` is a function that is generated in the .G.VB file associated with a XAML file.  If the .G.VB is not generated, there is no `InitialzeComponent()` function.

The steps that I have taken thus far are:

1. Compare the properties of the XAML file that is not generating a .G.VB to the properties of a XAML file that is producing a .G.VB file.
2. I tried a `Build | Clean Solution`; followed by a `Build | Rebuild Solution`.
3. Made sure that the namespace and class are the same in the VB and XAML x:Class.
4. Closed and re-started Visual Studio 2019.
5. Added a `InitializeComponent()` function to the class.
   *This will need to be documented so we know that this is typically automatically generated. Doing this leaves the code vulnerable to future changes made in the designer.*

The properties for the XAML file are set as:

- Build Action: `Page`
- Copy to Output Directory: `Do not copyist item`
- Custom Tool: `XamlIntelliSenseFileGenerator`

My questions are:

- What prevents the .G.VB file from being automatically generated?
- What is the best resource to diagnose the cause of this issue?

**Additional Information**

- I added a partial class with an `InitializeComponent()` method. This function calls `LoadComponent( uriLocator )` that loads the XAML referenced by the uriLocator string. This addresses the `undefined InitializeComponent()...` error in the short-term to get further information to identify the root cause.

Note that adding your own `InitializeComponent()` **should not** be seen as a solution.  It should only be used as a stepping-stone to find out why the .G.CS or .G.VB files are not being generated. The problem is that a custom G.CS or G.VB must be updated manually with any change to the XAML.

Comment: If Build Action is set to `Page`, you have to provide your on Main entry point (where you add, e.g., `var app = new MyApp(); app.InitializeComponent(); app.Run();`). The default Build Action of `App.xaml` or `Application.xaml` is `ApplicationDefinition`. This generates `App.g.i.cs` (or `Application.g.i.vb`)  etc. on build.

Comment: I had a similar issue when renaming classes. I missed the class name in the XAML `x:Class=xxx`

Comment: Xaml and code are partial classes. The xaml only knows about that cs or vb file by that x:class. The xaml relies in code to instantiate it. Initializecomponent is the statement turns xaml into controls.   If what you have in the xaml doesn't match what's on disk then there's no ctor with initializecomponent in it and instantiating that thing will give you no controls so it'll error. I don't know what that looks like in vb but i think jayv's suggestion is the first thing i'd look at.